# Instruments fails to execute send_keys intermittently. How should that be handled?

Tags: selenium, instruments, appium

**The Problem**: I'm using Appium's python client to `send_keys` to a `WebElement`.

And Instruments decides it shouldn't tap certain keys sometimes.
This is a pain when I'm trying to do things like login. **I need to be able to reliably type or programmatically set values** on input fields.

This is (more or less) what I'm doing, [and here's the gist of Instruments complaining about it](https://gist.github.com/JessicaSachs/4ced77f326338a4a1065):

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//UIATextField[1]')
el.click()
el.send_keys('ABCDEFGHI')
```

*All pretty standard. And it **usually** works*

But usually isn't cutting it. I need something solid.

---

**Possible Solutions?**

I think I can make `send_keys` work if I do some sort of try/retry if I get a `WebDriverException` back.

But what would be really cool is if I could set the value of the element through a JavaScript `execute_script` - or better yet - a selenium python binding!

I don't know JavaScript, and I've already tried searching for how to set the value on the object without doing `sendKeys` but I've come up blank.

Any ideas would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: That XPath looks pretty nasty! Can you optimize it? What is page code?

Comment: yeah, agreed. I can definitely optimize it, is there a best practice document for xpath usage/performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution below:

```
# Get the element

el = driver.find_element_by_class_name('UIATextField')
driver.execute_script("au.getElement('%s').setValue('%s')" % (el.id, 'ABCDEF'))

# At this point, the keyboard is opened and the text is instantly entered.
```